# Multiple versions of styled components installed (due to shared components with same dependencies)

Tags: npm, styled-components

I've got the following structure

```
root
--AppOne
----package.json
----node_modules
------styled-components

--AppTwo
----package.json
----node_modules
------styled-components

--Shared
----componentA
----package.json
----node_modules
------styled-components
```

My issue is that both AppOne and AppTwo are using a `componentA` from the `shared` directory, and it depends on `styled-components`

This means that I need to have `styled-components` installed in all three directories and I get the following error from `styled-components`:

`It looks like there are several instances of 'styled-components' initialized in this application.
This may cause dynamic styles not rendering properly, errors happening during rehydration process and makes your application bigger without a good reason.`

My question is - what is the best way to solve this situation? `AppOne` and `AppTwo` both use styled components, but they also both import shared components from the `Shared` directory which also uses styled components. How can I avoid multiple versions of `styled-components` being loaded?

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?